# Typical behavior or past habit

Tags: subjunctives

I'm not familiar with English language.
I want to know,

When we say:

> I'd tell lie.

Does it mean a typical behavior or a past habit?
In other words, is it like used to or is a present typical behavior?

Comment: "I'd tell lie" is not idiomatic English. "I'd lie" or "I'd tell **a** lie", representing "I would tell a lie", might represent **either** a past habit (under specific circumstances, eg "Whenever I was questioned I'd lie") **or** the consequence clause of a present irrealis conditonal, eg "If I were questioned I'd tell a lie". Context will tell you which is meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As StoneyB told you, *would* is not only used for conditional constructions. It depends of the given context if it's meant to be for repeated actions or habits in the past.

Note that for repeated *actions* in the past, you use *would*, but you can't use it for [*stative verbs*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stative_verb).

Also, if you stress *would*, it means that we find the behaviour irritating. For instance

> I hated when he ***would*** lie to me.